# Symfony 5 does not detect correct Locale in some requests

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, locale

I am struggling with how Symfony sets the locale.

This is my `annotations.yaml` file:

```
controllers_frontend:
resource: ../../src/Controller/Frontend
type: annotation
host:
  'de-DE': example.de
  'de-AT': example.at
  'de-CH': example.ch
  'fr-CH': example.ch
prefix:
  de-DE: '' # don't prefix URLs for German
  de-AT: ''
  de-CH: '/de'
  fr-CH: '/fr'
```

This works perfectly for route **"some-route" in Controller A:**

```
example.de/some-route -> locale = de-DE
example.at/some-route -> locale = de-AT
example.ch/de/some-route -> locale = de-CH
```

Then I have a different **Controller B** and and here I have the following problem:

```
example.de/swatch/checkout/confirm -> locale not detected, it goes back to the fall back locale
example.at/swatch/checkout/confirm -> locale not detected, it goes back to the fall back locale
example.ch/de/swatch/checkout/confirm -> locale = de-CH
```

Here is the code of that route

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Frontend;
...

class OrderController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/swatch/checkout/confirm", priority="10", name="swatch_checkout_confirm")
     */
    public function checkout_confirm(Request $request, OrderHelper $orderHelper)
    {
        $country = $orderHelper->getCountry($request->getLocale());

        return $this->render('frontend/order/checkout_confirm.html.twig',
            array(
                'country' => $country
            )
        );
    }
```

Since my locale setup in annotations.yaml works for "some-route", I believe it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. When I remove "priority" from the route, the locale is detected correctly. Not sure if that's bug in Symfony or my locale setup is wrong.